# Images not showing on android App after publishing apk from Smartface App Studio

Tags: smartface.io

I am publishing Android APK from Smartface App Studio and installed on my device. But, images are not loading/showing.

On the same device, getting all the images while i am running app with "Device Emulator".

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emulator and publish work different on resources. The important one is publish, therefore you should add icons to the related folder with the right screen resolution.

You can check the link below, it is about resource folder : 
http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/project/anatomy-project/#images

By the way, be sure that your icons are .png.
Otherwise they won't be used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah having all the images in respective resource folders in png format.
I tested with smartface icon image on my page. That is showing up. only my images not loading. 
Any license issues? I am having community license which is free.

Comment: Hey merve, got the solutions. Your links helps me to find out the issue. The real Issue is my images are having minus symbol which will not allow other than Alpha Numeric. Thanks for the help.